Storing Personal Google Account in Flutter App
I want to use my personal google account to send emails from the app and to upload documents to my google drive. I have everything set up in flutter, my only issue is authorization.
For more context: My app should have around 2-10 users. The user will fill some forms on my app, which will be exported as PDFs. I want to upload these PDFs to my personal GDrive and send them to a specific email from my personal email. To achieve this my credentials should somehow be saved on the app without expiration or risk of hacking. Is there a way to achieve this? or an alternative to this method?
OAuth2 the bane of my existence.

The whole architecture you have planned is much vulnerable. For this better use web services and do the risky things from  your secure server not from client.

The whole architecture you have planned is much vulnerable. For this better use web services and do the risky things from your secure server not from client.
Better Aproach
Step 1. Send the client responses to your secure server using REST API
Step 2. Generate the PDFs at server side
Step 3. Upload these PDFs to your personal GDrive
Step 4. Send the PDF through mail from secure server.
